# Why Does this JPA enum not work?

Tags: mysql, hibernate, jpa, enums

It is storing an integer in the database not the string as I requested.

Here is the class that contains the enum.

```
@Entity
@Inheritance(strategy=InheritanceType.JOINED)
public abstract class Document extends BaseModel {

    private String title = new String();
    private String description = new String();

    **@Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    private DocumentType documentType;**

    @Embedded
    private DocumentImage documentImage;
    // if document should be displayed or published on the web site.
    private Boolean published = new Boolean(false);

    public Document(DocumentType docType) {
        super();
        documentType = docType;
        setDocumentImage(new DocumentImage());

    }

}
```

and here is the enum class:

```
public enum DocumentType  {
    policy,procedure,webbookmark,newsrelease,collectionLetter,whitepaper,busform,
    newsarticle ;
}
```

I know this should work. Any ideas?

Comment: As you say, ought to work fine. Works fine on other JPA providers (e.g DataNucleus)

Comment: It looks fine. - Is your Dialect correct configured, and is it the Enumerated annotation from the right package?

Answer (score 1):

One possible reason is that your `@Enumerated` annotation doesn't take effect because annotations in `BaseModel` are placed on properties rather than on fields. Placement of annotations on fields or properties should be consistent across inheritance hierarchy.